# Angular 9 Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular9

### Updating to Angular 9 from 8 caused cyclic dependency error

I just upgraded to Angular 9 and I've fixed all the compilation errors. Now I'm getting an error related to a cyclic dependency that I can't track down.

```
Error: Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef
at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.js:8072)
at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:17049)
at R3Injector.get (core.js:16803)
at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:940)
at ɵɵinject (core.js:950)
at Object.NgbModalStack_Factory [as factory] (ng-bootstrap.js:6262)
at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:17053)
at R3Injector.get (core.js:16803)
at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:940)
at Module.ɵɵinject (core.js:950)
```

If I look at the ng-bootstrap.js:6262 block of code it looks like it's referring to the NgbModal component

```
    NgbModalStack.ɵprov = ɵɵdefineInjectable({ factory: function NgbModalStack_Factory() { return new NgbModalStack(ɵɵinject(ApplicationRef), ɵɵinject(INJECTOR), ɵɵinject(DOCUMENT), ɵɵinject(ScrollBar), ɵɵinject(RendererFactory2), ɵɵinject(NgZone)); }, token: NgbModalStack, providedIn: "root" });
NgbModalStack = __decorate([ __param(2, Inject(DOCUMENT))
], NgbModalStack);
```

This may not be directly related to the specific error, but I can't see anything that could cause this.
Anyone have a thought on what might cause this or could it be a bug in the Angular Bootstrap library?

Comment: did you try upgrading the dependencies too?

Comment: Definitely upgraded dependencies... including ng-bootstrap

Comment: **[This might help](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35225)**

Comment: Thanks Guruprasad, I looked over that particular bug posting and I don't think it applies to me. I don't think the error is getting generated in any sort of App Initialization service and I'm running Angular 9.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Any service which is injecting `NgbModal` service. During App-initializer

in my case i was injecting it inside a loader service.

So i removed loader service from app-initilizer and injected loader service into app.component.ts

It worked.

Answer (score 2):

I find this solution:

Not to inject directly in the constructor the NgModal, through of the Injector:

```
private modalService: NgbModal
constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

showModal() {
   // Inject the dependency of NgbModal 
   this.modalService = this.injector.get(NgbModal);
   this.modalService.open();
}
```